# Question about Modular Arithmetic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

Let $q$ be an integer number. Consider an integer number $N$ such that $\gcd(q-1,N) = 1$.

*Question:* How to show that if $q^d = 1 \pmod{N}$ for some positive integer $d$, then we get
$$
1 + q + q^2 + \cdots + q^{(d-1)} = 0 \pmod N \tag{1}
$$

*Try:* It follows from ($1$) that 
$$
1 + q + q^2 + \cdots + q^{(d-1)}=\frac{q^d-1}{q-1}
$$

Now the assumption $\gcd(q-1,N) = 1$ implies that $q-1\neq 0 \mod{N}$. Therefore, we get
$$
\frac{q^d-1}{q-1}=\frac{1-1}{q-1}=0 \pmod{N}
$$

Is the given proof correct?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: $\text {gcd} (q-1,N) = ?$

Comment: @Dbchatto67 - $\text{gcd}$ is a very common notation for the greatest common divisor function.

Comment: No, your proof is inadequate. $q-1 \not\equiv 0 \mod N$ does not necessarily mean you can divide by $q-1$. When $N$ is composite, $\Bbb Z_N$ has zero divisors, which do not have inverses, despite not being $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it. Note that although it's true $\gcd(q-1,N) = 1$ implies that $q-1 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{N}$, this is not sufficient. For example, if $N = 6 = 2 \times 3$, you also need to show that $q - 1 \not\equiv 2,3,4 \pmod 6$.

Given that $q^d \equiv 1 \pmod{N}$, this means that

$$q^d - 1 = kN \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

for some integer $k$. Since $q - 1 \mid q^d - 1$, then $q - 1 \mid kN$. Since $\gcd(q-1,N) = 1$, this means no factors of $q - 1$ can divide into $N$, so $q - 1 \mid k$. Thus,

$$k = \left(q-1\right)m \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

for some integer $m$. I trust you can finish the rest.

If you're familiar with certain number theory, note you can do this somewhat more simply using that given $\gcd(q-1,N) = 1$, then $q - 1$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $N$. Thus, you can go directly from $q^d - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$ to $\frac{q^d - 1}{q - 1} \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$.

Comment: (+) Nice and perfect answer. I like it.

Comment: @user0410 I'm glad you liked it. I usually try to give more basic, thorough answers that try to not assume too much about what the user already knows & is familiar with.

Comment: You are not just a user, but a good teacher. I appreciate your description.